# How to run a periodic task and a while loop asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have two functions:

```
i = 0

def update():
    global i
    i += 1

def output():
    print(i)
```

I want to run `output()` every 3 seconds and loop `update()` without any interval, both of course asynchronously.

I tried using `asyncio`, `threading`, `multithreading` and `timeloop` but I couldn't get it to work in neither of these libraries. If you figure out how to do it in any of these libraries, or some other library, please help. I'm ok with working with any library.

Comment: Have you tried out ```Celery```?

Comment: I heard it's very slow

Comment: Here's a very similar example with threading https://stackoverflow.com/a/72414738/2836621

Comment: Did the solution I proposed worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Using AsyncIO this would resemble:

```py
import asyncio


def update(value):
    value["int"] += 1

def output(value):
    print(value["int"])

async def update_worker(value):
    while True:
        update(value)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def output_worker(value):
    while True:
        output(value)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def main():
    value = {"int": 0}

    await asyncio.gather(
        update_worker(value), 
        output_worker(value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Notice that I changed the global value to be a shared value since it is best practice to do so. In other programming languages it would be unsafe to share a value both in read and write to multiple concurrent contexts but since most Python objects are thread safe is is ok in this case. Otherwise, you should use a mutex of any other concurrency primitive to synchronise reads and writes.

AsyncIO concurrency is based on a cooperative multitasking model so asynchronous tasks must explicitly **yield** control to other concurrent tasks when they are waiting for something (noted by all `await` keywords). Thus, to ensure that `output_worker` has a chance to run one must add an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in the infinite loop of the `update_worker` so that the AsyncIO event loop can run `output_worker`.

Here is the same code using multithreading instead of AsyncIO:

```py
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Lock

def update(value, lock):
    with lock:
        value["int"] += 1

def output(value, lock):
    with lock:
        print(value["int"])

def update_worker(value, lock):
    while True:
        update(value, lock)

def output_worker(value, lock):
    while True:
        output(value, lock)
        sleep(3)

def main():
    value = {"int": 0}
    lock = Lock()

    t1 = Thread(target=update_worker, args=(value, lock), daemon=True)
    t2 = Thread(target=output_worker, args=(value, lock), daemon=True)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Even though it is not necessary in this particular Python program, I used a `Lock` to synchronize reads and writes as it is the correct way to handle concurrency.