# How to receive data from a sensor at the same time that the data is sent to a website using Multiprocessing on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

I'm using nrf24L01 to collect data from a sensor and send it to a Raspberry Pi, and then the data is sent to a website.

The sensor needs to send data non-stop (it uses a fixed sampling of 2kHz)

However, during the request made by raspberry with the server, there is a small delay. As a result, the data sent by the sensor is lost, since the raspberry executes the functions sequentially: it receives the data, sends the data to the site, and thus remains in a loop.

I thought of using the Multiprocessing library. As the data is sent to the website, the raspberry continues to receive data from the sensor and store it in a buffer. That way I wouldn't lose the data due to the delay in communication with the server.

Is there any way to implement this using multiprocessing, and with the processes running in an infinite loop?

Here is an example:

```
import multiprocessing

def receive_data():

    #read the data that come from nf24L01 as a receiver
    #buffer the data
    print("Data received!")

def send_to_server():
    
    #read the data from the buffer
    #send to the server
    print("Data sent!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    #something link this
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=receive_data)
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=send_to_server)
    
    #I know I need to start the processes, but a didnt get it where I should do

    while True:
        
        print("Infinite loop")
        #both processess must run here
```

Comment: You could consider running 2 threads. One contnuously reads the sensor and pushes the readings into a queue. The other continuously reads from the queue and sends to the server.

Comment: For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: @itprorh66 Sure. I just edited the text and add an example.

Comment: Have a look at something similar here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/72414738/2836621

Answer (score 2):

Since the sensor is generating data faster (2K samplings per second) than the website can (currently) accept it, I would think that whatever "buffering" you use, such as the `threading.Queue` suggested by @MarkSetchell, you would be filling the queue faster than it can be emptied and eventually memory would be exhausted. If you can modify the web program, then I would batch the samplings into chunks of, for example, 2K samplings. That way you are only sending one large message per second. Despite the larger message, the network delay would not increase and you might be able to process the message on the website within one second. You could still use a queue to handle the variation in website response time.

I would be tempted to use multithreading since the main thread after it starts the child threads goes into a wait state and the `send_to_server` thread is mostly waiting for either a new item to be gotten from the queue or a response from the server. This would hopefully allow the `receive_data` thread adequate CPU resources, i.e. there should be very little GIL contention. That is not to say there might not be any GIL contention. It is imperative that `receive_data` does not miss a sensor reading and that `send_to_server` does not fall behind processing the queue or else it will eventually exhaust memory. Depending on the CPU speed and contention elsewhere, multithreading might be adequate and would be preferred since the queue communications would be less expensive (no need to serialize and de-serialize the data). You would have to try each one and see which one works (if at all):

**Multiprocessing Code**

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

CHUNK_SIZE = 2 * 1024 # 2K

def receive_data(q):

    #read the data that come from nf24L01 as a receiver
    #buffer the data
    
    while True:
        chunk = []
        while len(chunk) < CHUNK_SIZE:
            chunk.append(get_data_from_sensor())
        q.put(chunk)

def send_to_server(q):
    while True:
        send(q.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    # Make daemon processes and start send_to_server first.
    # When the main thread terminates, the started processes will also terminate:
    p1 = Process(target=send_to_server, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=receive_data, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    p2.start()
    
    try:
        input('Hit enter or Ctrl-c to terminate: ')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

**Multithreading Code**

```py
from threading import Thread
from thread import Queue

CHUNK_SIZE = 2 * 1024 # 2K

def receive_data(q):

    #read the data that come from nf24L01 as a receiver
    #buffer the data
    
    while True:
        chunk = []
        while len(chunk) < CHUNK_SIZE:
            chunk.append(get_data_from_sensor())
        q.put(chunk)

def send_to_server(q):
    while True:
        send(q.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    # Make daemon threads and start send_to_server first.
    # When the main thread terminates, the started threads will also terminate:
    p1 = multiprocessing.Thread(target=send_to_server, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    p1.start()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Thread(target=receive_data, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    p2.start()
    
    try:
        input('Hit enter or Ctrl-c to terminate: ')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

**Update**

If the time it takes the `receive_data` process/thread to put its chunk to the queue is so long because of its size as to cause it to miss one or more sensor readings, then you can adopt an alternate strategy where it is the `send_to_server` process/thread that does the buffering. For example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

CHUNK_SIZE = 2 * 1024 # 2K

def receive_data(q):

    #read the data that come from nf24L01 as a receiver

    while True:
        q.put(get_data_from_sensor())

def send_to_server(q):
    while True:
        # Buffer the data:
        chunk = []
        while len(chunk) < CHUNK_SIZE:
            chunk.append(q.get())
        send(chunk)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    # Make daemon processes and start send_to_server first.
    # When the main thread terminates, the started processes will also terminate:
    p1 = Process(target=send_to_server, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=receive_data, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    p2.start()

    try:
        input('Hit enter or Ctrl-c to terminate: ')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: Nice work! Btw, I didn't perceive the question as saying the sensor was always generating data faster than the website could accept. I understood that the there were occasionally delays in sending the data. Clearly if the data is permanently being read faster than it can be processed, some will need to be discarded else memory will fill up. I also didn't perceive the question as meaning that each of the 2k samples were sent individually - I assumed/understood that the samples came in chunks. If indeed they are currently sent individually I agree that chunking up is a great idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I will test it and give you a feedback! But I undestood perfectly your explanation!

Comment: I have added an update showing a possible alternate approach and I have also  shortened the code slightly for each child process.

Comment: I have done a little benchmarking and I think the original approach is the more efficient one (larger put fewer queue operations) and even with putting a larger piece of data (a chunk) that `receive_data` would not miss a sensor reading and if the response time for sending to the server is under a second, then `send_to_server` should be able to keep up  and the queue will not grow in size.